# How do i show and hide this loading bar using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, loading

I want to use this loading animation in my website but when I `show()` and `hide()` using jquery I do not get the desired result.

Also `.css('display', 'block')` and `.css('display', 'none')` does not have the desired effect either.

I am assuming this is because of how the css :not and :before is operating but my css skills arent great so I am unsure.

Loading animation codepen:
https://codepen.io/MattIn4D/pen/LiKFC

my code:

```
document.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight == document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
            $('.loading').show();
            $.getJSON('/json.php?prefetch', function(data) {
                    //json sorting here.
                });
        $('.loading').hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add the jQuery code you came up with.

Comment: updated with example of my code

Comment: A few notes - on line 2 you might want to do `>=` rather than `==` because you can't guarantee that the sizes will match exactly.
Secondly, you want `$('.loading').hide();` to happen after the data has fetched, so it should be inside the block marked `//json sorting here`, otherwise the `hide` will happen *immediately* after the `show` happens.

Comment: thankyou it works, i appreciate the help and also the browser height tip!

Answer (score 0):

Callback `$('.loading').hide();` inside your getJson function. this way your loading gif will hide when the getjson function runs. you can also check for your data and hide loading gif according to conditions.

```
document.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight == document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
            $('.loading').show();
            $.getJSON('/json.php?prefetch', function(data) {
                    //json sorting here.
                   $('.loading').hide();
                });

        }
    }
```